# How can I split a list into multiple lists of 3 elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

Say I have a list with 9 elements I want to split that list after every third element

```
["a", 1, 2, "b", 1, 2, "c", 1, 2]
```

Output:

```
["a", 1, 2]
["b", 1, 2]
["c", 1, 2]
```

Any suggestions toward this?

Comment: So basically you want groups of three right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 1):

**Does this help with your question?**

```
lst = ["a", 1, 2, "b", 1, 2, "c", 1, 2]

def chunks(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

for i in chunks(lst, 3):
    print(i)
```

RESULT:

```
['a', 1, 2]
['b', 1, 2]
['c', 1, 2]
```

**CREDIT: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)**

If you any other queries or doubts feel free to ask to me I'll be there!
Happy Coding!

Comment: If you think this question has an answer somewhere else in this site - [flag it as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead of posting another answer as an answer...

Comment: Okay will do that